# Save model object to SQL Server from R

Tags: sql-server, r

I'm fitting hundreds of models and I don't want to spend the compute time to refit the models when I reuse them every month.  I don't want to come up with a file naming convention if I don't have to so I'd rather write the model object to SQL.  I know the `save()` function writes a binary object out - is there a way I could write that binary object as a `blob` to SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not a binary object, `capture.output(dump("model",file=""))` will create an ascii representation of the object `model`.  It has some special characters in it, so to execute it it requires `eval(parse(text=gsub("[\r\n]","",capturedOutput)))`.

So, a model called `model` can be captured with the code above.  This can be written to a database however you're connecting to a database (`sqlSave` from RODBC if you prefer).  Then, when read from the database, the second line of code will work to execute the model.